# Get main content from url

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying to build an iOS app like Pocket or Instapaper for practice. So, I need to fetch data from a url and strip the HTML of of it. I created the code below to do this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.link];
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"webData is: %@", webData);

NSString *finalhtmlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", webData];
finalhtmlstring = [finalhtmlstring stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

NSLog(@"FinalHTMLString is: %@", finalhtmlstring);
```

How would I fetch the body of the page? I can't get the `NSString` between `@"<body>"` and `@"</body>"`, because some websites add attributes to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: You could use a `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: Thus leading us to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/97337

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like parsing XML or HTML page.

Fortunately, there is open-source libraries likes [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) can help you to get the contents from wrappers easily.

It wraps libxml2 nicely using Objective-C objects

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) about how to use this library.